# Swift UIViewController Custom init() - Error cannot assign to self

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, initialization

In Objective-C I used to override the `init` method of my `UIViewController`. I cannot achieve the same in Swift :

Objective-C code :

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If I try to do so in Swift I get errors for "Cannot assign to self". I have already implemented the `initWithCoder:` method just to get through a few more errors.

Can someone please tell me how can I port the above Objective-C code to Swift to get the desired behavior.

I want to init the ViewController from storyboard.

Comment: http://creativeiphonecoding.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-initialise-view-controller-in.html

Comment: @MithunMadhav I just read the blog and I cannot get the result I am expecting

Comment: You cannot set 'self' in the init method. Use a public function of the ViewController's class to create and initialise using the storyboard. Then present that

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign `self` in `init`. You should use `class` method or public function instead.

```
class func viewControllerFromStoryboard() -> ViewController? {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: ViewController.self))
    if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as? ViewController
    {
        return controller
    }
    return nil
}
```

After you can call

```
let controller = ViewController.viewControllerFromStoryboard()
```

Answer (score 0):

Init method in swift is different from the ones in objc.

In objc `the only requirement for init method is that the initializing method begins with the letters “init”`. You create a instance in this method and assign to pointer `self`

whereas in swift `Initializing is the process of preparing an instance of a class, structure, or enumeration for use`. It's kind of like you already has a `self` point to an instance. What you do in init method is set up self's properties and other

That's why you cannot assign to self in swift for class

but you can assign to self in a mutating method of struct

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write like this

```
class func customInit -> XXXController {
    var vc: XXXController = XXXController()
    //  write something that you want to initialize 
    return vc 
}
```

just like you write objc

```
- (instancetype)initCustom {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       //  write something that you want to initialize 
    }
    return self; 
}
```

and you can cell

`var customVc: XXXController = XXXController.customInit()`

just like

`XXXController *vc = [[XXXController alloc] initCustom]`