# UIView instancetype from Obj-C at Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, instancetype

Hello everyone I'm getting close to programming Swift then feel right away that I'm new to Swift

In my project in Obj-C I created many classes `UIView` that I used in my app

I have a problem with the implementation of these classes `UIView` from Obj-C for Swift ...

In short, until now I have always used this...
My class `UIView` had various init with frame etc ... but a directly instancetype that elaborated all

```
-(instancetype)initializeNotificationViewWithTitle:(NSString *)notificationTitle
                               notificationMessage:(NSString *)notificationMessage
                                  notificationType:(UTNotificationType)notificationType
                                  notificationMode:(UTNotificationMode)notificationMode
```

now I can not fit it in Swift many of you surely know that Swift is the most simple of Obj-C but I still can not adapt

You can make me understand how to implement this function I posted this in Obj-C Swift ?

Comment: How were you able to create constructor like that intiailizeNotificationViewWithTitle:. Did compiler throw any error, it should either be initIalizeNotificationViewWithTitle: or initWithNotificationViewTitle:

Comment: to me it has always worked very well give me back without even a warning ... but swift as I recall a customized init in a specific view controller?

instantiatetype swif in how it implemented

Comment: Well thats related to how objective c works your method is instance method and you can call it after you have alloced it. But that is not proper initializer in Objective C either. So, it could not infer that to swift properly.

Comment: ok you can make me an example? to better understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you provided looks like a simple init method and init method in swift looks like

```
init(title: String, message: String, type: UTNotificationType, mode: UTNotificationMode) {
    //init
}
```

and use it as

```
let aView = NotificationView(title:"title", message:"message", type: someType, mode: someMode)
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer ... but I have a problem after the implementation of your solution ...

after entering
init (title: String, message: String, type: UTNotificationType, mode: UTNotificationMode) {
     // init
}

the compiler gives me an error:

super.init is not called before returning from initializer

They are probably too deep to obj-C to understand swift although everyone says that it seems much simpler ... I can not understand why I returns this error

Comment: @rory because indeed super.init() is not called, It's just an example. It seems you haven't learned about init method in swift. My another [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799088/swift-uiviewcontroller-custom-init-error-cannot-assign-to-self/30803863#30803863) might help you understand but except that you really need to read init method chapter in the swift programming language